# Calling injected dll function from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, dll

My scenario is following:

I have this application, into which I injected a dll. This dll upon loading changes some of the instructions in the application and also has some functions which are loaded. My question is how would I go about calling those newly imported functions from the altered instructions in the application. More specifically I'm unsure about whether I can use just directive "CALL" and name of function or I'll need to specify the exact address. If the latter is the case does the fact that the dll is in another module affects the address in any way? If so how?

Thanks in advance for any help and if my question is not clear enough ask and I'll try to clarify what I had in mind.

P.S.: Off topic: why the hell I cannot add "Hello there!" at the beginning of my post... It always gets deleted :(

Comment: I am linux developer, in linux you must use dynamic link library in order to use dynamic linked function. in linux you compile your program with dynamic link library and then use simple 'CALL` instruction to use your dynamic link function. that was your mean ?

Comment: Not exactly because I have only binary form of the app. I'm injecting dll into so I cannot just link dll into the code and then compile it.